# self._NgForm_14_3.context is not a function

Tags: angular2-forms

My Code:

```
<form role="form" #login="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(login.form)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="adviserUsername">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="adviserUsername" #username="ngModel" placeholder="Enter Username" type="text" name="adviserUsername"
          required>
          <div *ngIf="username.touched && username.errors">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="passwordText" #password="ngModel" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
          type="password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.touched && password.errors">Password is required</div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="login()" [disabled]="!login.valid">Login</button>

    </form>
```

Error which I am getting is

self._NgForm_14_3.context is not a function
Here's a Snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is simple 
I was using a click event on the button click - which was using login() - this was double reference and created a problem ...

Code:
Line Fixed >>

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" [disabled]="!login.valid">Login</button>
```